# How can i fix my constructor error problem while trying to build jda app?

Tags: java, constructor, discord-jda

I am using Jda, Spring boot, h2 database, i tried to make random joke command for my discord bot

```
@Service
public class BotJokeService extends ListenerAdapter {

    private final ChuckNorrisQuotes quotes = new ChuckNorrisQuotes();
    private final PlayerRepository playerRepository;

    public BotJokeService(PlayerRepository playerRepository) {
        this.playerRepository = playerRepository;
    }

    

    @Override
    public void onMessageDelete(MessageDeleteEvent event) {

        event.getGuild().getDefaultChannel().asTextChannel().sendMessage(quotes.getRandomQuote()).queue();

    }

    //
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event) {
        // User user = event.getAuthor();
        if (!event.getAuthor().isBot()) {
            String message = "!joke";
            if ("!joke".equals(message)) {
                //  event.getGuild().mute(user, true).queue(); mute

                event.getChannel().asTextChannel().sendMessage(quotes.getRandomQuote()).queue();
                Player random = new Player();
                random.setName(message);
                random.setRole("yes");
                random.setCreatedDate(LocalDateTime.MAX);
                playerRepository.save(random);

            }
        }
    }

}
```

and now i want that my jda listen to BotJokeService class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DcBot1Application  {
    
    @Autowired
    private EmailSenderService emailSenderService;
    public static String prefix = "-";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws LoginException {
        SpringApplication.run(DcBot1Application.class, args);
        JDA bot = JDABuilder.createDefault("here goes my bot token")
                .setActivity(Activity.playing("example"))
                .addEventListeners(new MessageSending(),
                        new Help(), new BotJokeService())
                .build();
    }
}
```

but new BotJokeService() gives me eror  constructor BotJokeSerivce in class BotJokeSerivce cannot be applied to given types, i know it need constructor but how to initalize my PlayerRepository constructor here ?

Comment: `BotJokeService` is a service, you have to autowire it, don't instantiate it manually.

Comment: how to autowire botjokeservice i dont get it, jda listens class only if u add class on addeventlisteners whenever i try to add botjokeservice it gives constructor error , how to autowire my class please define ((

Answer (score 0):

You can get a bean in the main method like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    BotJokeService service = context.getBeanFactory().getBean(BotJokeService.class);
    //do whatever you need with the service now
  }
}
```

I haven't used the discord api before, but application startup does not look like the best place to create the bot instance.

Comment: JpaApplication.class does not exists

Comment: @user20572341 Use your start class, that would be `DcBot1Application.class`, according to your question...